# How to parse AgentExecutor (ReAct) feedback to Streamlit?

Tags: streamlit, langchain, py-langchain

I wanted to stream my ReAct agent "Action Input" to my Streamlit app

The problem that I have is that the agent pipes the feedback into the shell but not the screen. Documentation doesn't really help.

Here is my agent definition

```
    llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo")
    tools = load_tools(["human", "serpapi", "llm-math"], llm=llm)

    prefix = """Some agent definition.
            Ask appropriate questions. 
            You have access to the following tools:"""
    suffix = """Begin!"
 
    {chat_history}
    Question: {input}
    {agent_scratchpad}"""

    output_parser = CustomOutputParser()
    prompt = ZeroShotAgent.create_prompt(
        tools,
        prefix=prefix,
        suffix=suffix,
        input_variables=["input", "chat_history", "agent_scratchpad"],
   )
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")
    llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
    agent = ZeroShotAgent(llm_chain=llm_chain, tools=tools, verbose=True, output_parser=output_parser)
    agent_chain = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
    agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True, memory=memory
    )
```

and this is my streamlit part. The streamlist code works with a standard OpenAI call with stream=true

```
if prompt := st.chat_input("What is up?"):
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})
    with st.chat_message("user"):
        st.markdown(prompt)

    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        message_placeholder = st.empty()
        full_response = ""
        for response in agent_chain.run(st.session_state.messages):
            full_response += response.choices[0].delta.get("content", "")
            message_placeholder.markdown(full_response + "▌")
        message_placeholder.markdown(full_response)
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": full_response})
```

The conversation happens in the shell but not the front-end.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB8tM.png)

Answer (score 1):

you can initialize the agent with return_intermediate_steps=True

```
 ZeroShotAgent(llm_chain=llm_chain, tools=tools, verbose=True, output_parser=output_parser, return_intermediate_steps=True)
```

Now you can read response as below and parse it basis your requirement

```
response = agent_chain.run("your query")
print(response["intermediate_steps"])
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem that I have is that the "thoughts" of the agent end up in the shell but not the streamlit site.

Comment: hint : message_placeholder.markdown(response["intermediate_steps"])